# jquery modal dialog overlay doesn't take full screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery modal dialog and it doesn't grey out the screen fully when you bring it up. If I take a look it is attributed to this css code:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1920px; height: 628px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

This is from the custom css generated with jquery's [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Not sure why those dimensions were created?  If I select a higher number for height it covers more of the screen but I'm wondering if there is a value I can use to take the whole screen.  I tried `100%` and `auto` for height but they don't do anything.

The dialog size is fine it is just the greyed out overlay behind the dialog. I want this greyed out part behind the dialog to take the size of the full screen. For reference here is my dialog options I'm using:

```
var dialogOpts={
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 525
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Comment: Not the asker, but I wanted to add a comment saying that I was having this exact problem and this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and this is how i fixed it:

```
<style>
    .ui-widget-overlay
    {
        height: 100vw;
    }
</style>
```

Now, `vw` is View Width, and you want the Modal Overlay to cover the whole screen. The "correct" measure should of been `vh` (View Height) but when I tried that, it didn't work.

Here's a link for [vh and vw](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/).

I hope this helps, 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    position: ["left","top"],
    width:"100%",
    height:$(window).height(),
    zIndex: 1000            
});
```

Comment: I believe what your suggesting is changing the modal dialog size. That's not what I want. I just want to change the overlay, you know the greyed out part behind the dialog. Right now it doesn't go full screen.

Comment: why don't you do it backwards, set it like in my code, and change the title background to the size you want. The effect should be the same.Or if you want to keep other part like it is in the dialog, without streching it to a whole screen, just set it some width/height, and then strech the whole dialog.

Comment: I use dialogs in a few places. Sometimes it just has some text and other times it has forms. Stretching the dialog looks awful.